# Problem with reading several Netcdf files using Xarray

Tags: python-xarray, netcdf4

I have been trying to read a set of netcdf files using Xarray in python. When reading a single file, using *xarray.open_dataset*, the file could be read as I intended, as given below.
[reading a single file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VT7Hf.png)

I couldn't find this attribute called "group" in *xarray.open_mfdataset* without which, I cannot read the files properly.
[reading multiple files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjU9O.png)

When I try to read the single file without this attribute, the output is similar. So  I assume this is due to the "group" attribute.
[reading single file without "group" attribute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2kTB.png)

I appreciate it a lot if someone could help me get this clarified. Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please see this [guide to asking questions](/help/how-to-ask), and specifically, [please do not post images of code, tracebacks, or data](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Instead format them as code blocks - images are not searchable, they can't be read by people with visual impairments, and they make reproducing the problem more difficult for us. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried just passing in the group argument to `xr.open_mfdataset`? The [docs](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.open_mfdataset.html#xarray.open_mfdataset) say any additional keyword arguments (`**kwargs`) are passed to xr.open_dataset, so I would assume group would work just fine...

Comment: Hi  @MichaelDelgado Thanks for your reply. I tried it and I still get the following error message.[Errno group not found: PRODUCT] 'PRODUCT'

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include both the code you've tried and the [full traceback](https://realpython.com/python-traceback/)? Also the error message seems to suggest that one of the files does not have a group of that name. Can you check to make sure they're all formatted the same and not corrupted?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.